# RxSwift concurrency problems with coordinator

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift, rx-cocoa

**What I want to do**:

1. Present VC1
2. When VC1 is dismissed, present VC2

**Problem**:

1. When VC1 is dismissed, VC2 does not present

**Dirty Fix**:
Put milisecond delay. It fixes the problem, but want to know why it happens

**Explanation**: I get viewDidDissapear event when VC1 dismisses so I can present VC2

**If you need more details, please ask.**

**Code**:

```
class ViewModel {

    let coordinator = Coordinator()

    struct Input {
        let itemSelected: Driver<IndexPath>
    }

    struct Output {
        let presentVC1: Driver<Void>
        let presentVC2: Driver<Void>
    }

    func transform(input: Input) -> Output {

        let navigateToVC1 = input.itemSelected
            .flatMap { [coordinator] in
                return coordinator.transition(to: Scene.VC1)
            }

        let navigateToVC2 = navigateToVC1
            .delay(.milliseconds(1))
            .flatMap { [coordinator] in
                return coordinator.transition(to: Scene.VC2)
            }

        return Output(presentVC1: presentVC1, presentVC2: presentVC2)
    }
```

Coordinator code:

```
func transition(to scene: TargetScene) -> Driver<Void> {
        let subject = PublishSubject<Void>()

        switch scene.transition {
           
            case let .present(viewController):
                _ = viewController.rx
                    .sentMessage(#selector(UIViewController.viewDidDisappear(_:)))
                    .map { _ in } 
                    .bind(to:subject)
                currentViewController.present(viewController, animated: true)
                
        return subject
            .take(1)
            .asDriverOnErrorJustComplete()
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `viewDidDisappear` method is called before the view controller is fully dismissed. You should not try to present the second view controller until the callback of `dismiss` is called.

Wherever you are dismissing your view controller, use the below instead and don't present the next view controller until after the observable emits a next event.

```
extension Reactive where Base: UIViewController {
    func dismiss(animated: Bool) -> Observable<Void> {
        Observable.create { [base] observer in
            base.dismiss(animated: animated) {
                observer.onNext(())
                observer.onCompleted()
            }
            return Disposables.create()
        }
    }
}
```

I suggest you consider using my Cause-Logic-Effect architecture which contains everything you need to properly handle view controller presentation and dismissal.

https://github.com/danielt1263/CLE-Architecture-Tools

A portion of the interface is below:

```
/**
Presents a scene onto the top view controller of the presentation stack. The scene will be dismissed when either the action observable completes/errors or is disposed.
- Parameters:
- animated: Pass `true` to animate the presentation; otherwise, pass `false`.
- sourceView: If the scene will be presented in a popover controller, this is the view that will serve as the focus.
- scene: A factory function for creating the Scene.
- Returns: The Scene's output action `Observable`.
*/
func presentScene<Action>(animated: Bool, overSourceView sourceView: UIView? = nil, scene: @escaping () -> Scene<Action>) -> Observable<Action>

extension NSObjectProtocol where Self : UIViewController {

    /**
        Create a scene from an already existing view controller.
    
        - Parameter connect: A function describing how the view controller should be connected and returning an Observable that emits any data the scene needs to communicate to its parent.
        - Returns: A Scene containing the view controller and return value of the connect function.
    
        Example:
    
        `let exampleScene = ExampleViewController().scene { $0.connect() }`
        */
    func scene<Action>(_ connect: (Self) -> Observable<Action>) -> Scene<Action>
}

struct Scene<Action> {
    let controller: UIViewController
    let action: Observable<Action>
}
```

The `connect` function is your view model, when its Observable completes or its subscriber disposes, the view controller will automatically dismiss.

The `presentScene` function is your coordinator. It handles the actual presenting and dismissing of scenes. When you dismiss and present a new scene, it will properly handle waiting until the previous view controller is dismissed before presenting the next one.

Comment: Thank you Daniel T. for help. Appreciate it.